# Motion of a particle near a charged plane

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, classical-electrodynamics

Consider a positive charge density in the $x-y$ plane, its electric field is $\vec{E}=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}\hat{z}$. At moment $t=0$ a particle with positive charge $q$ begins to move with velocity $\vec{v}_0 = v_{0x}\hat{x}+v_{0z}\hat{z}$ in the lab reference frame. A driver in car that moves with velocity $\vec{v}_{car} = v_{0x}\hat{x}$.

From a non-relativistic point of view the particle moves is a parabolic fashion in the $x-z$ plane at the lab system. It will experience a constant electric force in the $z$ direction. In the $x$ direction there is no force so the particle's velocity in this direction is constant. 
While the driver observes a current density due to the moving plane charge with a magnetic field $\vec{B}=\frac{\mu_0\sigma v_{0x}}{2}\hat{y}$ that exerts a Lorentz force will have a non-vanishing component in the $x$, plus the usual electric field.

Obviously there is a contradiction here. Where does it lie?

A relativistic analysis, given in Landau and Lifshitz, section 20 shows - 
$$v_{x}=\frac{c^{2}p_{0}}{\sqrt{\mathcal{E}_{0}^{2}+q^{2}E^{2}c^{2}t^{2}}};\;v_z\frac{qEc^{2}t}{\sqrt{\mathcal{E}_{0}^{2}+q^{2}E^{2}c^{2}t^{2}}}$$

and - 
$$x=\frac{p_{0}c}{qE}\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{qEc}{\mathcal{E}_{0}}t\right);\; z=\frac{1}{qE}\sqrt{\mathcal{E}_{0}^{2}+q^{2}E^{2}c^{2}t^{2}}$$
With $\mathcal{E}_0$ the particle's initial energy.

So the particle does feel a force in the $x$ direction of the lab frame (it's velocity's $x$ component goes to zero). They assume $v_{0z}=0$ but this isn't important (we may assume the driver begin its movement when  the particle reaches $\vec{v}_0$).

How does the particle's movement looks like in the driver's frame?

Is it possible to use Lorentz transformation -
$$x=\frac{x'+v_{0x}t'}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v_{0x}^{2}}{c^{2}}}};\;t=\frac{t'+\frac{v_{0x}}{c^{2}}x'}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v_{0x}^{2}}{c^{2}}}};\;y=y';\;z=z'$$
Where $x,t$ are in the lab frame and $x',t'$ are in the drivers frame, and get -

$$x'=\frac{p_{0}c}{qE}\sqrt{1-\frac{v_{0x}^{2}}{c^{2}}}\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{qEc}{\mathcal{E}_{0}}\frac{t'+\frac{v_{0x}}{c^{2}}x'}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v_{0x}^{2}}{c^{2}}}}\right)-v_{0x}t'$$
$$z'=\frac{1}{qE}\sqrt{\mathcal{E}_{0}^{2}+q^{2}E^{2}c^{2}\frac{\left(t'+\frac{v_{0x}}{c^{2}}x'\right)^{2}}{1-\frac{v_{0x}^{2}}{c^{2}}}}$$

Comment: @Frobenius I Fixed it

Comment: The particle does not experience force in the x direction, but its velocity component in this direction does change. This is because in special relativity, acceleration is not strictly proportional to force; the Newton 2nd law is no longer valid.

Comment: @can you elaborate? there will be a a change of momentum in the $x$ direction, which the definition of force

Comment: In the frame where there is only electric field, $F_x = 0 = d(\gamma m v_x)/dt$. Both $\gamma$ and $v_x$ change in such a way that $\gamma m v_x$ does not change. In the moving frame where there is also magnetic field, $F_x'$ is no longer zero. In special relativity, force is not invariant when changing frames, so one can have force component zero in one frame and non-zero in other.